# Disable link to the current page in navigation

Tags: php, javascript, css, xhtml

I have a pretty standard navigation for a website. The main navigation is a ul, with several nested ul's. I'm basically just wanting to dynamically disable a link when the user is already on that page.

So if I'm on the home page, the home page link needs to be disabled. If I'm on the contact page, the contact page link needs to be disabled.

I am not wanting to delete the link entirely, just remove the href from the anchor or just make the anchor itself de-activated. Is there a fast, slick and elegant solution for this in XHTML, CSS, JavaScript or php. I'd also want a solution that's friendly across the board, not just for modern browsers (you can read, IE 6).

I did think of setting a path variable on each page, and then having an if statement for each link, but that seems horribly tedious and stupid. But hey, it would get the job done.

Comment: I'd say that's about the default: let the code generating your navigation check which page is current and disable the link to that page / omit the anchor tag. How you'd like to check it is your concern, you could even basically check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` & the resulting url, and omit the tag if they match.

Comment: Thing is, I am not dynamically generating the navigation, so I guess I'd have to make an if statement around each link, then use your suggestion of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] with an algorithm to get it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be best to do this in the page generation code (i.e. PHP), iterating through each link and removing the `<a>` tag, replacing it with a `<span>` or something similar if the link matches the criteria for matching the current page.  PHP gives you this current page (in various flavors: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, etc.) in its base, and using these, you can determine an algorithm to match your page.

Comment: Thing is, I am not dynamically generating the navigation, so I guess I'd have to make an if statement around each link, then use your suggestion of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] with an algorithm to get it right.

Comment: As I normally cache my webpages (object and  html static cache), I prefer using javascript for doing that, because the caching strategy does not allow two versions of the same page generated by PHP (just one of them will enter the cache and stay there, for a long time).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript for removing href attribute from `<a>` tag:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for( var i=0; i < anchors.length; i++ ) {
    if ( anchors[i].getAttribute('href') === win.location.href ) {
        anchors[i].removeAttribute('href');
        //anchors[i].setAttribute('class', 'unlinked'); add for IE8
    }
}
```

CSS for disabling link events:

```
a:not([href]) {
/* a.unlinked { */  use in place of the line above for IE8
    pointer-events:none;
    color:inherit;
}
```

It works with IE9 or higher.

For IE8, you have to use the alternative lines of code (see comments).

For IE6 or IE7, the `<a>` tag must be removed and in its place a `<span>` tag with the same text must be inserted (removing href do not work for them).